# read all values from multiple documents within a single file into an array with yq

Tags: yaml, yq

I use [mikefahra's yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) 4.40.5 and try to read values from a files which may contain multiple documents into one array.

I want to get all `.port` and `.nodePort` fields into one array which is contained in the file `kind-config.yaml`

*kind-config.yaml*

```
kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.ui/v1alpha4
nodes:
  - role: control-plane
    extraPortMappings:
      - containerPort: 3333
        hostPort: 30333
     # add the ports from the files below to this array
```

Here's how the files look like (they are helm service files)

*File 1, multiple docs*

```
apVersion: 1
kind: Service
spec:
  ports:
    - name: my-port
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      nodePort: 30808
---
apVersion: 1
kind: Service
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: my-name
  ports:
    - name: my-external-name
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      nodePort: 30666
```

I can get those information like:
`yq ea '.nodes[0].extraPortMappings += [load("file1.yaml") | .[].spec.ports[] | select(.nodePort) | {"containerPort": .port, "hostPort": .nodePort}]' ./kind-config.yaml`

*File 2, one document*

```
apVersion: 1
kind: Service
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: my-name
  ports:
    - name: my-external-name
      port: 7000
      targetPort: 7000
      nodePort: 30700
```

the script from above fails here because `.[].spec` is not an array, if I change it to `.spec` it works again.

But I would prefer if I could solve both my use cases with only one script.

So, is it possible to get the data I need with one single script for both files with multiple docs and those which only contain one?

P.S.
I dont mean that I can process multiple files simultaneously with one script, but that I can use the same script.

EDIT:
I think it has something to do with how I use `load` because if I just read the the values I can use the same script for both files.
`yq ea '[.spec.ports[] | select(.nodePort) | {"containerPort": .port, "hostPort": .nodePort}]' file1.yaml`

Seems that `load` will load all the documents within a file into an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `load`ing the file, you can build a gate that either selects a single map or iterates over the sequence: `select(kind == "map") // .[]`. From then on, you can treat both inputs as structurally identical:

```bash
filter='.nodes[0].extraPortMappings += [
  load(strenv(file)) | select(kind == "map") // .[] | .spec.ports[]
  | select(.nodePort) | {"containerPort": .port, "hostPort": .nodePort}
]'
```

```bash
file=file1.yaml yq ea "$filter" ./kind-config.yaml
```

```yaml
kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.ui/v1alpha4
nodes:
  - role: control-plane
    extraPortMappings:
      - containerPort: 3333
        hostPort: 30333
      - containerPort: 8080
        hostPort: 30808
      - containerPort: 8080
        hostPort: 30666
# add the ports from the files below to this array
```

```bash
file=file2.yaml yq ea "$filter" ./kind-config.yaml
```

```yaml
kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.ui/v1alpha4
nodes:
  - role: control-plane
    extraPortMappings:
      - containerPort: 3333
        hostPort: 30333
      - containerPort: 7000
        hostPort: 30700
# add the ports from the files below to this array
```

Note that for this sample, you actually don't need the `ea` command. If not needed by other parts of your actual script, you could either change it to `e`, or drop it altogether. Tested with mikefarah/yq v4.40.5.